# MatrixTransform in combination with Width/Height of a Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, scrollviewer, matrix-transform

When zooming in on a drawing on a Canvas I have the requirement to show scrollbars.
The Canvas is in a ScrollViewer and I increase the Width/Height of the Canvas so that that the scollbars appear (otherwise they don't).

To zoom in with a factor of 1.1 I use this code:

```
Matrix m = this.LayoutTransform.Value;
if (e.Delta > 0) f = 1.1;
else f = 1.0 / 1.1;
m.Scale(f, f);
this.LayoutTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);
this.Height = this.ActualHeight * f;
this.Width = this.ActualWidth * f;
```

It turns out that the Canvas becomes much too large. The drawing zooms in 10% but the width seems to become 20% more like the square of 1.1. So I use `Math.Sqrt(f);` instead of `f`.

Can anybody explain why it behaves this way?

Comment: You seem to apply the scaling factor twice, first by the LayoutTransform and second by multiplying Width and Height. You should do only one of these, preferably only the LayoutTransform.

Comment: Then the scrollbars do not appear (which is a requirement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only change the LayoutTransform of the Canvas, like in this simplified example:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Canvas Width="1000" Height="1000" Background="Transparent"
            MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel">
        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <MatrixTransform/>
        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The MouseWheel event handler:

```
private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var transform = (MatrixTransform)element.LayoutTransform;
    var matrix = transform.Matrix;
    var scale = e.Delta >= 0d ? 1.1 : (1d / 1.1);

    matrix.Scale(scale, scale);
    transform.Matrix = matrix;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Does it work without `Width="1000" Height="1000"`? My Canvas has no initial size, it fits to its parent size and the drawing dimensions too.

Comment: It has to have an initial size, otherwise the ScrollViewer doesn't make sense. You may however set the initial size in code behind as soon as it is available.

Comment: One more question: when I reset the Transform back to Identity, the scrollbars remain visible, while initially they are not visible (which is good) and the Canvas size hasn't changed.

Comment: One more question: when using RenderTransform instead of LayoutTransform the scollbars do not appear despite setting Width&Heigth.

Comment: First question: hard to tell without seeing your code. Second: RenderTransform does not influence layout, but you need that. You can't use RenderTransform here.

Comment: Is it possible perhaps to combine Render- and LayoutTransform, because the RenderTransform zooms much more nicely.

Comment: I don't think so. As said before, you need the layout to be recalculated in order to update the scrollbars.