# Get canvas current scale

Tags: javascript, canvas, scale

I am currently working with a canvas that holds shapes. So I want to be able to keep the shapes size while zooming in or out. 
I think that I need to know the canvas scale or the dpi, so I can recalculate the shape dimensions. My questions

- Is there better solution for that?
- If I am on the good track how can I get the current scale of a canvas? I am looking for something like in the code below. 
  `let scale = ctx.getCurrentScale();`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you have it in getTransform but only in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No long ago I had an issue, and Clemens helped me with that :

[Zoom on Canvas, centered on mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128551/zoom-on-canvas-centered-on-mouse-position)

take his solution then "play" with it it will help you understand better.